# Windows 10 Pro stopped using half of the RAM

Tags: windows-10, memory

Basically, I have 16GB of RAM (HX428C14SB/8, two sticks), and it worked perfectly well for around 3 years, but then they stopped. The only significant thing that happened to my PC around this time was me adding a second monitor to my setup. What happens now is that both motherboard (MSI Z170A Gaming Pro) and System Properties still say I have 16GB, but when I enter Task Manager and check it by percentage and amounts used, it's clear that only 8GB is used, and so programs that take me beyond that amount of RAM crash.

I made sure my system is updated, updated the bios, checked if both sticks work both with memtest and by launching computer with singular sticks, I checked the if the slots it's inserted into work, I tried with dual channel as well as without (those 3 years when it worked were without dual channel), I did all the combinations of settings in BOOT Advanced Options and Paging Files that are supposed to work according to tutorials, and at this point I'm reasonably sure I'm not missing something obvious.

So, this is my problem, and I welcome all the suggestions as to what might be wrong because I don't have any more ideas.

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: @Rainbow - How much memory have you allowed for `hardware reserved`?

Comment: possible duplicate of https://superuser.com/questions/34168/why-would-windows-only-recognise-half-a-stick-or-ram?rq=1

Comment: @Rainbow - All vital information should be contained within the question body.  Information contained with a comment is easily missed.  Comments are designed to be temporary.  Images not uploaded using the image upload functionality will prevent other editors, from being able to inline screenshots.

Comment: Its extremely hard for an average user, even a gamer, to actively use more than 8 GB or RAM.  Your crashing is more likely due to something else.